# How to extract original images from a lossless compressed video which is composed from a sequence of images?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, images, compression, h.264

I am trying to compress a sequence of images using h.264 with ffmpeg.

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -r 5 -i ori/binary%03d.jpg -vcodec libx264 -preset veryslow a.mp4
ffmpeg -i a.mp4 -q 2 rec/output_%03d.jpg
```

but the output images are still different from the original images.
What is the correct way to generate a lossless video and extract original images from it?

Comment: H264 isn't lossless. In fact, neither is JPEG. Have you tried motion JPEG? " -vcodec mjpeg"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## H.264

Standard H.264 is lossy, so when you go from JPG > H.264 > JPG you have two [generations of loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_loss). Enable [lossless mode](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264#LosslessH.264) in libx264 by adding `-crf 0`:

```
 ffmpeg -framerate 5 -i ori/binary%03d.jpg -c:v libx264 -crf 0 -preset veryslow lossless.mp4
```

Now you can check the decoded hash of each frame using the [framehash](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#framehash) muxer:

```
ffmpeg -v error -i lossless.mp4 -f framehash -
[...]
#stream#, dts,        pts, duration,     size, hash
0,          0,          0,        1,   230400, 2c3b4546159721bb2328a56bb520d15d45a4d6a845a31a3ac41ae2bbe27188d9
0,          1,          1,        1,   230400, 597803e630b0f50d0e703293367747d00798677950cf2b1398258335e8753ba8
0,          2,          2,        1,   230400, 64d37a10a1841126c9ad8804c0ec20ac89f102d737ffd787d9f963c4c3ea9bc1
[...]
```

Compare with the JPG inputs:

```
ffmpeg -v error -i ori/binary%03d.jpg -f framehash -
[...]
#stream#, dts,        pts, duration,     size, hash
0,          0,          0,        1,   230400, 2c3b4546159721bb2328a56bb520d15d45a4d6a845a31a3ac41ae2bbe27188d9
0,          1,          1,        1,   230400, 597803e630b0f50d0e703293367747d00798677950cf2b1398258335e8753ba8
0,          2,          2,        1,   230400, 64d37a10a1841126c9ad8804c0ec20ac89f102d737ffd787d9f963c4c3ea9bc1
[...]
```

In this example the hashes are the same verifying a lossless conversion.

You can't extract the original JPG even when using lossless H.264, but you can now output to another lossless image format.

Note that with PNG inputs the hashes won't match due to colorspace conversion. Using libx265rgb for PNG is recommended: the hashes will still not match unless gbrp is converted to rgb24.

## MJPEG

Or just mux your JPG images into a video. Think of it as a copy and paste. They are just dumped in as-is and played one after the other:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 5 -i ori/binary%03d.jpg -c copy video.mkv
```

To extract:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mkv -c copy output%04d.jpg
```

Comment: I try  ffmpeg -framerate 5 -i ori/binary%03d.jpg -c:v libx264 -crf 0 -preset veryslow lossless.mp4 but the mp4 file generated is even bigger than the size of the ori folder,why? :0

Comment: The goal of the above attempt is to losslessly compress a set of continuous images. I guess h.264 uses the information between frames to help compression,but with the cmd you mention above, it generate bigger file.

Comment: @curtank Lossless can create huge files. It's not a fair comparison because you're comparing the JPG, which has the advantage of already being compressed, to the H.264 output which has to deal with the increased entropy introduced by the compression artifacts. If you want to "losslessly compress a set of continuous images" then avoid using JPG altogether. Ideally use the source that you used to create the JPG directly to ffmpeg to output a lossless format.